# Javascript function for both instead of each one separately

Tags: javascript, if-statement, jscrollpane

I have this piece of code for a jScrollPane that changes the top arrow's class when it's at the top of the page (since it can't scroll any higher) and the bottom arrow's class when it's at the bottom of the page (since it can't scroll any lower):

```
if (settings.showArrows) {
$upArrow[destY == 0 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
$downArrow[destY == maxY ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
}
```

I would like to change it so that either both arrows are showing (when scrolling in either direction is possible) or both arrows are disabled (when all content is visible).

Thank you.

Comment: If that code is fired when you scroll and `maxY` is initialized properly, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (settings.showArrows) {
$upArrow[destY == 0 && destY == maxY ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
$downArrow[destY == 0 && destY == maxY ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
}
```

Or even:

```
if (settings.showArrows) {
$upArrow[maxY == 0 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
$downArrow[maxY == 0 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
}
```